# typescript relay reactjs IRTransformer: Unknown kind `undefined`. using hasura

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relay, hasura

Hi i got this error which i got before, but i forgot how i solved it.

I created a new query for Relay but I get this error. I remember it has to do something with Typescript, but not sure what i did wrong.

```
ERROR:
IRTransformer: Unknown kind `undefined`.
error Command failed with exit code 100.
```

It is not pointing to a particular place in my code, so not sure which code snippet i should include...

this is the query (but it could easily be another one):

```
const getEvent = `query CreateEventQuery {


eetschema_event_connection(where: {group_id: {_eq: "17ee3ff5-eae1-4482-9ad6-d791a46a9799"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

script I run is `yarn relay` and the problem is at the yarn-compile step

```
"export-schema": "get-graphql-schema https://XXXX.hasura.app/v1beta1/relay -h 'x-hasura-admin-secret=XXXXX' > ./schema.graphql",
    "relay-compile": "relay-compiler --src=./src --schema=./schema.graphql --language typescript ",
    "relay": "npm run export-schema && npm run relay-compile",
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow reinstalling the relay compiler worked for me.

yarn add relay-compiler-language-typescript